# User input on Pivot table or a table created by Power query and update the source data with the user input

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerquery

I have an inventory table, and a user checks items to be removed from the table.
The user uses Pivot table to check the items.

My ultimate goal is to remove items the user checked.

My idea is, add a column to the Pivot table for user input.
The user enter "0" (or anything) in a cell of the added column, and then the entered value will be updated to the data source table. From there, I can filer out the entered value.

Here's the visualized idea:

Pivot table:
[image]

Data source table:
[image]

I have tried having a user to put "0" in a cell of a column next to the pivot table, and then used vlook up to get items with "0" in the data source. However, the column is not linked to Pivot table, so if someone filters the Pivot table, the column value and the pivot table value are not matched anymore since they are not linked.

My questions are:

1. how do I insert a blank column for user input to Pivot table? Is it possible?
2. if 1 is possible, then how the values in the added column above can be updated to the data source?
3. if 1 is impossible, are there any other ways to achieve my goal?

Comment: What is the data source of the pivot table? Powerquery? SQL? something else?

Comment: The data source is a table in Excel.